# Unity 16.04 fade

Tags: unity, compiz

I don't know how it happened, maybe I changed some Compiz setting.  Now all my Unity windows start fading / blurring gradually and become unreadable. 
I tried to `unity reset` and `docnf reset /org/compiz` but can't get rid of this fade.

Any help remove this "feature"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing **sudo unity --reset** and **sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz** in a terminal. If that doesn't work, it's probably easiest to install a different desktop environment. I recommend gnome.

1. Log off, then on the login screen press [Ctrl+Alt+F1].
2. Sign in with your username and password. (These steps let you use the terminal without it fading away)
3. Type **sudo apt-get install gnome**.
4. Now you must investigate. There could be a few things that happen now: all files failed to "fetch", in the download process, the system asks about adding an entry to unity-greeter, or the operation completes successfully.

A. Try typing ping google.com. If that doesn't work, check your internet connection and try again. If it still doesn't work, check Ubuntu Software Center. If that doesn't pull up, try again later or, if your dual-booting, try the Internet in the different OS.

B. If it asks about adding an entry, click yes. This is very important. You can now continue on.

C. Continue on if it is successful.

5. Now when you log out, there should be a box above your username. Click this, and one option in the box should be **gnome**. Click this, and then login. Open a terminal in gnome and type **sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity**.
6. When the process completes, log out, and then click "default" in the box mentioned earlier. Now it should work like normal.

If you need any more help or I didn't make myself clear, let me know as I'm happy to help.

Comment: Thanks.. sudo unity --reset and sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz i seem to have fixed it!

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Open Compiz Config Manager and search for "Fade" in the upper left, uncheck "Fading Windows"